# How to plot positive and negative examples with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot negative and positive examples in a graph with their respective colors (Positive = green, Negative = black) i recognize a positive or negative example with the column vector (y), this is a binary vector, for example... if i have a couple of X values in a determinated index, i compare their same index with the (y) vector, and if the y(index) == 1, it's a positive example, on the other hand if y(index) == 0, that means it's a negative example

But, when a try this...

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    plt.plot(X[i,1], X[i,4])
plt.show()
```

The graph appers empty, and if i try putting this...

```
plt.plot(X[:,1], X[:,4])
plt.show()
```

It returns to me a graph with the points but not with the colors because i don't know how to put the colors making the comparison with the (y) vector
I hopefully you can help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of incomplete. You should have given an example for x and y. If I understand correctly, the problem with your code is this part: `plt.plot(X[i,1], X[i,4])`
using `plt.scatter(X[i,1], X[i,4])` instead could probably solve your "not showing anything" problem.

I made some mock up data and have a look if this is what you meant. x and y are the axes, posneg provide the information about positive and negative number as you wanted it to be.

```
x = np.array(([3,2,1,4,5]))
y = np.array(([1,2,3,2,1]))
posneg = np.array(([0,1,0,0,1]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)):
    if posneg[i] == 0:
        c = 'k'
    else:
        c = 'g'
    ax.scatter(x[i],y[i], color=c)
```

And I guess the thing that you have been looking for is this `color` option?

Above code will give following output:
[image]